# Unable to archive build using XCode 6.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I know there are few posts related to this issue but none of them is helping me. Ever since I have shifted to XCode 6.0.1, I am not able to archive and generate an ad-hoc build. It gives me following error every time. Tried removing and re-installing provisioning profile, tried clicking on Try Again button on the alert. It works pretty well with XCode 5.1.1.

Is there some specific guidelines to follow to make this work. Please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently archived for AdHoc and this is what worked for me:

1) Go to "Build Settings"

2) Under "Code Signing" click the dropdown button for "Provisioning Profile"

3) Set "Release" to your app's AdHoc Provisioning Profile

4) Then Archive.

5) When the Organizer window pops up, click "Export" (Not submit!)

6) Then save it for Ad Hoc deployment.

That could do the trick!
If not, login to your dev center and make sure the Provisioning profile you created for your app is indeed "Ad Hoc" and matches your bundle identifier.  This provisioning profile is the one you should be selecting in the above Step #3.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Upvoting as this sounds promising. I shall try this out.